# angular momentum of electromagnetic wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, polarization

EM waves that are circularly or elliptically polarized have angular momentum.
Is there any experiment that proves/shows this ? like shine a light on something and it rotates ?
   The correspondence is made to spin angular momentum from a QM viewpoint.But how exactly is the link made. How does the correspondence principle work here ?

Comment: You mean something like "Mechanical Detection and Measurement of the Angular Momentum of Light"
Richard A. Beth, Phys. Rev. 50, 115 – Published 15 July 1936?

Comment: These are two very different questions and they should really be asked separately.

Comment: I assume you have looked at the Wikipedia article: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_of_light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_of_light)

Comment: For a quick qualitative intro you might also like this article about a way to transform photon "spin" into orbital angular momentum: http://physics.aps.org/story/v17/st15.